# Inserting subfigures between text

Tags: graphics, floats

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{MainFolder/a.png}} 
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{MainFolder/b.png}} 
    \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{MainFolder/c.png}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I am using above commands for adding sub figures. Required layout is

> text text  text.... subfigures text text text ... subfigures .

Subfigures appear at the top of the page.

Comment: Could you make your code compile please? You can use `example-image-a` from the `graphicx` package etc, we do not have access to your figures. Also you can use the `lipsum` package to make dummy text so we can see the format you desire, how do you two subfigures but have only included one `\begin{figure}` with no text in between? Please help people help you (:

Comment: your example stops with `! Undefined control sequence. l.7     \subfigure`

Comment: but you have placed the images in a `figure` the only function of `figure` is to allow the content to move, perhaps you want `\begin{figure}[htbp]` so it will try to not move it if it fits.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text